# HSQLDB, persist method with jpadao and Java out of memory

Tags: java, jpa, persistence, eclipselink, hsqldb

I would use hsqldb and eclipseLink to save my data.
I create the file persistence.xml in which i save all my entity. The file is so composed:

```
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">

    <persistence-unit name="myDB" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>myClass</class>
        <class>....</class>
        <class>myClass</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:file:myDB"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="SA" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Note that i use the property `RESOURCE_LOCAL`

After that i have this class to use the persist method:

```
public abstract class JpaDAO<E> {

    protected Class<E> entityClass;

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myDB")
    protected EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("myDB");
    protected EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public JpaDAO() {
        ParameterizedType genericSuperclass = (ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
        this.entityClass = (Class<E>) genericSuperclass.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public List<E> findAll() {
        TypedQuery<E> q = em.createQuery("SELECT h FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " h", entityClass);
        return q.getResultList();
    }

    public E findById(Long id) {
        return em.find(entityClass, id);
    }

    public E flush(E entity) {
        em.flush();
        return entity;
    }

    public E merge(E entity) {
        return em.merge(entity);
    }

    public void persist(E entity) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.persist(entity);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }

    public void refresh(E entity) {
        em.refresh(entity);
    }

    public void remove(E entity) {
        em.remove(entity);
    }

    public Integer removeAll() {
        Query q = em.createQuery("DELETE FROM " + entityClass.getName() + " h");
        return q.executeUpdate();
    }

}
```

I tried to save the data calling this:

```
JpaDAO<myClass> dao = new JpaDAO<myClass>() {
};
dao.persist(objectOfMyClass);
```

But when i try to execute that i find this error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.resize(IdentityHashMap.java:452)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:428)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectClone(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4293)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.registerNotRegisteredNewObjectForPersist(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4235)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeRegisterNewIfRequired(CollectionMapping.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeRegisterNewForCreate(ObjectBuilder.java:2542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeRegisterNewIfRequired(CollectionMapping.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeRegisterNewForCreate(ObjectBuilder.java:2542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.CollectionMapping.cascadeRegisterNewIfRequired(CollectionMapping.java:516)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.cascadeRegisterNewForCreate(ObjectBuilder.java:2542)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.registerNewObjectForPersist(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:4241)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496)
    at util.JpaDAO.persist(JpaDAO.java:48)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6414)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6179)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2084)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4776)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2142)
```

How can i fix this? Now i save my data into a file and this file is large 5MB.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a recursive cascade to me. Would you mind to share the code of myClass?

Comment: Yes, there are recursive cascades but actually i cannot post the complete code of myClass because is too long...any help? Have I missed something in the configuration?

Comment: I assume you did already increase the memory for theJVM?

Comment: When i save the data into a file they occupy only 5MB...is a problem of eclipse memory?